# How to gather row id's of sheet that is being imported?

Tags: python, excel, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am currently trying to move rows from a sheet I import, into another existing sheet. As of right now I am using `result.data.id` to return the sheet id that will be associated with the imported sheet. For further clarification here is the line of code I am using to move the rows.

```
response =smart.Sheets.move_rows(result.data.id,smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({'row_ids': [**IDK**],'to': smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({'sheet_id': 1174866712913796})}))
```

I run into my issue when it prompts me to enter the row ids that I am trying to move into the existing sheet. As the imported sheet has not been created yet, I can not reference the row ids within the smart sheet. My question is: Is there something similar to `result.data.id` but for row ids? Or is there something else I can enter for row_ids that will just move all the rows in a sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to copy all rows from the sheet you've just imported, you should be able to use the [Copy Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#copy-sheet) operation. As the documentation shows:

- You specify the `id` of the sheet you want to copy, and information about the container (e.g., folder) where you want the new sheet to be created.
- You also have the option of including additional parameters that specify which types of things you want to be included in the copy operation (e.g., attachments, discussions, forms, etc.)

Here's an example request in Python:

```
response = smart.Sheets.copy_sheet(
  4583173393803140,                               # sheet_id
  smartsheet.models.ContainerDestination({
    'destination_type': 'folder',               # folder, workspace, or home
    'destination_id': 9283173393803140,         # folder_id
    'new_name': 'newSheetName'
  })
)
```

**UPDATE (list rows):**

Since I now understand that you want to copy all rows from the sheet you import into another sheet *that already exists*, the **Copy Sheet** approach that I've described above isn't appropriate.

Instead, after you've imported the sheet, you can use the [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) operation to get data about the sheet you've imported. Here's an example of the **Get Sheet** operation in Python:

```
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(
  4583173393803140)           # sheet_id
```

The response will contain (amongst other things), a `rows` property, which is an array of `Row` objects, representing all of the rows in the imported sheet. Each [Row](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#row-object) object contains an `id` property that specifies the ID of the row.

You'll need to iterate through that array of `Row` objects, adding the value of each `id` property to a comma-delimited list of IDs -- this will give you the list of IDs that the **Move Rows to Another Sheet** operation requires.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I have looked into this function, and although it is close to what I am trying to achieve it is not exact. Copy sheet allows me to move my imported sheet into a new folder, workspace or home. I am essentially trying to copy a sheet into another sheet.

Comment: Ah -- okay. So, just to clarify: do I understand correctly that you want to move all rows from the imported sheet into another sheet ***that already exists*** ?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've updated my answer with additional info that should help with your scenario. Please mark the answer as 'accepted' if appropriate, and also 'upvote' it as well -- doing so will make others more likely to benefit from this information in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Kim, I appreciate the direction. However, I am pretty new to python and the smartsheet API. I have tried to write a for loop to iterate through the get sheet info. But I am receiving an error that states that the 'Sheet' object is not iterable. I then tried to get sheet as a csv and iterate that way, but alas I got a similar error. Do you know what type of object I need to convert the get_sheet info into in order to iterate it?

Comment: You don't want to iterate through the `Sheet` object -- you want to iterate through the `rows` property of the `Sheet` object.

Comment: If you can't get things working (i.e., figure out how to iterate through `sheet.rows` and compile the comma-delimited list of row IDs, please post a new question here on Stack Overflow and someone will help.